# python setuptools Include man page in RPM

Tags: python, setuptools, manpage

for create rpm with setuptools i use this command:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

but i want to include man page in the rpmbuild, setuptools can include my manpage.gz in rpm package automatiquely ?

i create manpage file and crompress in gz file, but i want to include in my rpm automatiquely when i export my code in rpm package with setuptools

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?